# A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'SpecificationID'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations

I'm having a similar problem to existing questions with teh same title, but its slightly different.

I get the error:

> **A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'SpecificationID'.**

When I try to save to database:

```
var doc = new Specification();
doc.ProjectComponentID = spec.ProjectComponentID;
doc.Description = spec.Description;
db.Specifications.Add(doc);

db.SaveChanges();
```

When I created the database I used the seed method to map a 1 to 1 or none relationship:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Specification>()
            .HasRequired(pc => pc.ProjectComponent)
            .WithOptional(s => s.Specification);
```

My 2 relevant entities are:

```
public class ProjectComponent
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProjectComponentID { get; set; }

    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

    public int ProjectPhaseID { get; set; }
    public virtual ProjectPhase Phase { get; set; }

    ... other properties ...

    public Nullable<int> SpecificationID { get; set; }
    public virtual Specification Specification { get; set; }
}

public class Specification
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SpecificationID { get; set; }

    public int ProjectComponentID { get; set; }
    public virtual ProjectComponent ProjectComponent { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

I need to be able to add a specification to a PRojectComponent. providing the specification with the ProjectComponentID but auto generating the SpecificationID

I don't get any error on creating the DB, only when trying to save the Specification.

Answer (score 0):

So I found "A" solution. But I'm not convinced its the "best" solution.

Apparently code-first EF requires the primary keys to be shared in a one to zero or one relationship.

So to solve this issue I have removed the foreign keys on each entity:

```
public class ProjectComponent
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProjectComponentID { get; set; }

    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

    public int ProjectPhaseID { get; set; }
    public virtual ProjectPhase Phase { get; set; }

    ... other properties ...

    public virtual Specification Specification { get; set; }

}

public class Specification
{
    public int SpecificationID { get; set; }
    public virtual ProjectComponent ProjectComponent { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and I modified the Fluent API to an inverse of the previous:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectComponent>()
            .HasOptional(pc => pc.Specification)
            .WithRequired(s => s.ProjectComponent);
```

now when saving to the database, I have no issues and it usses the ProjectComponentID foreign key as the SpecificationID primary key:

```
var comp = db.ProjectComponents.Find(spec.SpecificationID);
comp.Specification = new Specification {Description = spec.Description};

db.SaveChanges();
```

Please comment if anyone has a better solution... but this is the only way I could find to solve it as a pure code-first managed DB